# Trying to make a box plot in R but it looks very odd

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, boxplot

I'm trying to group some data on a box plot: there's 3 points in each of the 3 groups. This is what my data looks like:

[image]

and here's my code following a ggplot2 tutorial online:

```
data <- read_excel("Desktop/")
data$`Genome_size` <- as.factor(data$`Genome_size`)
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Group, y=Genome_size)) + geom_boxplot()
plot + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1)
```

It gives me this:

[image]

The way it's laid out is how I want it to be, with the genome size on the y axis and the 3 groups separated, but I'm not sure why it looks like this? Is it because I have too few values and I'm better off doing a bar graph?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post images of data (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). It's better to provide data one of: public dataset like `mtcars`, `iris`, `diamonds`; programmatically with `data.frame(..)`; or the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is the minimum needed to show the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I think is that your Genome_size column is factor type.

Try this :

```
data <- read_excel("Desktop/")
data$`Genome_size` <- as.numeric(as.character(data$`Genome_size`))
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Group, y=Genome_size)) + geom_boxplot()
plot + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1)
```

Comment: When I run this code, it changes the data in my genome_size column to single digits for some reason, but it does fix the weird line issue! So not too sure :(

Comment: What do you mean by 'single digit'

Comment: Is there a way to retain the integers? They're quite important for the plot

Comment: It changes the numbers to 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 6, 9 ,8 and 2 (if you read it down) and this is also on the plot too!

Comment: Ok try then as.numeric(as.character(data$Genome_size))